# How to test payments in Facebook Instant Game?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games, facebook-payments

I cannot seem to make a test dialog appear. When I call `payments.purchaseAync`, I am always presented with a real Checkout dialog as opposed to a test dialog.

[image]

I've already added the test user to the Testers. Am I missing anything? Or is this feature not supported yet at this time?

[image]

Temporary code I'm using:

```
let supportedAPIs:any = FBInstant.getSupportedAPIs();
if(supportedAPIs.includes('payments.purchaseAsync'))
{
    console.log('payments supported...');

    FBInstant.payments.onReady(() => {
        console.log('payments ready...');

        FBInstant.payments.purchaseAsync({
            productID: 'test_product',
            developerPayload: 'foobar',
        }).then(function (purchase) {
            console.log(purchase);
        });
    });
}
else
{
    console.log('payments not supported...');
}
```

Comment: Is that user id you added in the settings an app-scoped user id belonging to your app?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, its the id for the test user that appears under Roles > Test Users > User ID

Comment: Are you testing it on the mobile device or on browser/embedded mode? I've had a well-configured purchases but I couldn't test it on an Android device. It seems that only users set as Developers or Administrators can test payments.

Comment: @ezpn It should work on an Android device but not in the desktop / browser. And yes, the account I ended up using is a real one with developer access.